# Coverting python list to smaller list or numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, dataframe, numpy

I have python lists which look like this:

```
[{'t': 1617632700048595399,
  'y': 1617632700048396000,
  'q': 1409807,
  'i': '17243',
  'x': 19,
  's': 1,
  'c': [37],
  'p': 124.99,
  'z': 3},
 {'t': 1617632700057416219,
  'y': 1617632700057000000,
  'f': 1617632700057380078,
  'q': 1409817,
  'i': '56377',
  'x': 4,
  'r': 202,
  's': 1,
  'c': [37],
  'p': 124.995,
  'z': 3},
 {'t': 1617632700417168459,
  'y': 1617632700416962000,
  'q': 1410030,
  'i': '3612',
  'x': 18,
  's': 100,
  'c': [14, 41],
  'p': 125,
  'z': 3},
 {'t': 1617632700417224575,
  'y': 1617632700417208240,
  'q': 1410032,
  'i': '38548',
  'x': 12,
  's': 100,
  'p': 125,
  'z': 3},
 {'t': 1617632700417289090,
  'y': 1617632700417083000,
  'q': 1410034,
  'i': '26498',
  'x': 8,
  's': 50,
  'c': [37],
  'p': 125,
  'z': 3}]
```

They usually contain more than 500K element (by element I mean data blocks in each curly brackets, these data blocks are not always the same size, they may contain different number of records but they always have a parameter name). I need to process them as efficient as possible and would like to convert them to simple numpy array or smaller list which ideally look like this:

```
1617632700048595399,124.99,1
1617632700057416219,124.995,1
1617632700417168459,125,100
1617632700417224575,125,100
1617632700417289090,125,50
```

Which is basically only 't','p' and 's'. Later I will save them in a hdf or csv file or write them into a database. I am not sure a pandas dataframe is a solution as well.

Comment: If the elements don't have the same number of attributes, numpy isn't the right place to store them

Comment: What is your input data source? If a file, what is it's format text, csv, json, other?

Comment: The data comes from a REST API.

Comment: Any suggestion if numpy is not the solution? I revised the title.

Comment: Whats your actual problem?

Comment: That's a list of dicts, possibly originally JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can beat the naive approach performance-wise:

```
with open("results.csv", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join(f"{d['t']},{d['p']},{d['s']}" for d in data))
```

Or, if you want to separate extraction and writing:

```
results = [(d['t'],d['p'],d['s']) for d in data]
with open("results.csv", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join(f"{r[0]},{r[1]},{r[2]}" for r in results))
```

Comment: This is a great solution. THX

Answer (score 1):

To save the data in CSV format, you can use `csv` module (`lst` is your list):

```
import csv

with open("data.csv", "w") as f_out:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(
        f_out, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
    )
    for item in lst:
        csvwriter.writerow([item.get("t"), item.get("p"), item.get("s")])
```

Saves `data.csv`:

```
1617632700048595399,124.99,1
1617632700057416219,124.995,1
1617632700417168459,125,100
1617632700417224575,125,100
1617632700417289090,125,50
```

Comment: Great. But how can I filter elements first before saving to csv? because I may need to do some manipulation before saving.

Comment: @Bob What elements do you want to filter? Simple `if ...` before `csv.writerow` might be enough.

Comment: 't', 'p' and 's'.

Comment: @Bob So do `if item.get('t') == ... and/or item.get('p') ...` etc before `csv.writerow` to fiter out the elements you don't need.